# Random "Login failed for user 'NT Authority\Anoymous Login'" errors in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, windows-authentication

We have a asp.net web application that uses windows authentication It was previously using sql authentication. We are consistently (but randomly) getting "Login failed for user 'NT Authority\Anoymous Login'" errors in production. Most of the times, the application works fine. From SQL server database perspective, the SPN's and delegations are in place.
The connection string looks like:

```
<add name="SomeName" connectionString="Data Source=<SomeDataSource>;Initial Catalog=<SomeInitialCatalog>;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient">
```

What could the underlying issue be?

[image]

Comment: Is the server running SQL Server domain joined? And if so, how good is the network connection to the domain controller server?

Comment: Thank you @CharlieFace, We have several web applications that run using similar connection strings and use the same app pool as the offending web service application. None of the other web applications have reported this issue. I am not sure about "server running SQL Server domain joined". Both the webserver and the database server are on the same domain.

Comment: Check whether user ‘NT Authority\ANONYMOUS LOGON’ permissions are granted in the properties of the database file. Insufficient permissions may be a problem.